# How to boot macOS in KVM?

Tags: ubuntu, mac, virtual-machine, linux-kvm

> **Note:** this question assumes the host running KVM is running on actual Apple hardware, to comply with the macOS license agreement.

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 Server on a late-2014 Mac Mini and installed the KVM packages. I can connect to KVM using `virt-manager` on another host in the network.

I would like to install macOS Sierra in a virtual machine. Here's what I've tried:

- I downloaded the "Install macOS Sierra" app from the Mac app store and used it to create a bootable USB drive. I verified the USB drive works by doing a test install on the Mini using the drive.
- I also created an ISO file from the installer app.
- I completed the "Create a new virtual machine" wizard in `virt-manager`, using the following options:

  - **Choose how you would like to install the operating system:** "Local install media"
  - **Locate your install media:** "Use ISO image"
  - **OS Type:** Other
  - **Version:** MacOS X Lion
  - **Memory:** 2048
  - **CPUs:** 2
  - **Enable storage for this virtual machine**
  - **Create a disk image for the virtual machine:** 100.0 GB
- I assigned the name "sierra" to the virtual machine.
- I installed the `omvf` package in Ubuntu and changed the firmware for the VM to point to the `OVMF_CODE.fd` file.
- Then I opened up a SSH session to the Mini and ran the following command:

  ```
  virsh edit sierra
  ```
- I added the following `<disk>` definition (for the USB drive):

  ```
  <disk type='block' device='disk'>
    <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
    <source dev='/dev/disk/by-uuid/UUID-GOES-HERE'/>
    <target dev='vdb' bus='virtio'/>
  </disk>
  ```

  (replacing the `UUID-GOES-HERE` with the appropriate value)

When I attempt to boot the virtual machine, I end up with the following:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think it should work if you change your disk type to sata

Comment: The github repo [foxlet/macOS-Simple-KVM](https://github.com/foxlet/macOS-Simple-KVM) might be helpful